# Why does one variable work, while the other one doesn't, and the two variables are very similiar

Tags: javascript, p5.js

https://editor.p5js.org/Meowmeow/sketches/b4AhGA4xH

This is created using a web editor for p5.js. Whenever you make something with j, it has an error message unless you do Cell =>. If you do it with i, there's no error message. The variables i,j are changed in the same places, unless I did something by accident. If I did please point it out, otherways can someone tell me why this happens?

```js
var cols, rows;
var diffeculty = 0;
var w = 50;
var grid = [];
var stack = [];
var current;
var check = []
var k = 0;
var m = 0;
var won = false;

function setup() {
  //frameRate(10)
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  cols = floor(width / w)
  rows = floor(height / w)


  for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
      var cell = new Cell(i, j)
      grid.push(cell)
    }
  }

  current = grid[0];
}
function index(i, j) {

  if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i > cols - 1 || j > cols - 1) {
    return -1;
  }
  return i + j * cols
}

function Cell(i, j) {


  this.visited = false;
  this.i = i;
  this.j = j;
  this.walls = [true, true, true, true];
  this.checkNeighbors = function() {
    var neighbors = []
    var top = grid[index(i, j - 1)]
    var right = grid[index(i + 1, j)]
    var left = grid[index(i - 1, j)]
    var bottom = grid[index(i, j + 1)]
    var Wall = this.walls;
    
    var wall=[]
    wall.push(i,j,Wall)
    
    
    if (top && !top.visited) {
      neighbors.push(top);
    }

    if (right && !right.visited) {
      neighbors.push(right);
    }
    if (bottom && !bottom.visited) {
      neighbors.push(bottom);
    }
    if (left && !left.visited) {
      neighbors.push(left);
    }

    if (neighbors.length > 0) {
      var r = floor(random(0, neighbors.length))
      return neighbors[r];
    } else {
      return undefined;
    }

  }

  this.highlight = function() {
    var x = this.i * w;
    var y = this.j * w;
    noStroke();
    fill(0, 0, 255, 100)
    rect(x, y, w, w);

  }
  this.show = function() {
    var x = this.i * w;
    var y = this.j * w;
    stroke(255);
    noFill();

    if (this.walls[0]) {
      line(x, y, x + w, y);
    }
    if (this.walls[1]) {
      line(x + w, y, x + w, y + w);
    }

    if (this.walls[2]) {
      line(x + w, y + w, x, y + w);
    }
    if (this.walls[3]) {
      line(x, y + w, x, y);
    }

    if (this.visited) {
      fill(255, 0, 255, 100);
      noStroke();
      rect(x, y, w, w);
    }
  }
};






function removeWalls(a, b) {
  var x = a.i - b.i;
  if (x === 1) {
    a.walls[3] = false;
    b.walls[1] = false;
  } else if (x === -1) {
    a.walls[1] = false;
    b.walls[3] = false;
  }
  var y = a.j - b.j;

  if (y === 1) {
    a.walls[0] = false;
    b.walls[2] = false;
  } else if (y === -1) {
    a.walls[2] = false;
    b.walls[0] = false;
  }


}

function draw() {
  background(51);
  for (var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    grid[i].show()
  }


  //Step One
  current.visited = true;
  current.highlight();

  var next = current.checkNeighbors()
  if (next) {
    next.visited = true;

    //Step 2
    stack.push(current);
    check.push(current)

    //Step 3
    removeWalls(current, next) 
    {}


    //Step 4 
    current = next;
  } else if (stack.length > 0) {
    current = stack.pop();

  }


  if (stack[0] === undefined) {
    fill(0, 105, 100)
    rect(0, 0, w, w)
    rect(width - w, height - w, w, w)
    frameRate(8)
  
    
   var c =  check.find(cell => cell.i == ~~(k/w) && cell.j == ~~(m/w));
    
    
    //console.log(c)
    

    
    
    if(c===undefined)
      {
        console.log(m,cell =>j)
        console.log(k,i)
      }
    
    if(keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)) {
      k -= w
    }
    if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)) {
      m += w
    }
    if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW)) {
      k += w
    }
    if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)) {
      m -= w
    }

    fill(0, 255, 255, 100)
    rect(m, k, w, w)

    if (m < 0) {
      m = 0
    }
    if (k < 0) {
      k = 0
    }
    if (m > width - w) {
      m = width - w
    }
    if (k > height - w) {
      k = height - w
    }

    if (k === height - w && m === width - w || won === true) {

      won = true
      background(0)
      textSize(40)
      text("You Win", width / 2, height / 2)
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You must add the relevant code to the question. A link to an off-site resource is not sufficient. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: So how does one create the error?

Comment: Not really sure how to recreate the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to generation of the maze. Some cells are twice and some cells are missing in the `check` array. You must add the `next` cell to the array instead of the `current` cell. The current cell contains the previous position in the maze:

```js
function draw() {
    background(51);
    for (var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
      grid[i].show()
    }

    var next = (stack.length == 0) ? grid[0] : current.checkNeighbors();
    if (next) {
        //Step One
        next.highlight();
        next.visited = true;

        //Step 2
        stack.push(next);
        check.push(next);

        //Step 3
        if (current && current != next)
            removeWalls(current, next);

        //Step 4 
        current = next;
    } else if (stack.length > 0) {
        current = stack.pop();
    }

    // [...]
```